# How to extract category from Google Plus listing of businesses?

Tags: python, api, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

For example, 
this link is of Google Plus profile of Tesco Extra,
https://plus.google.com/112519049895518094921/about
 , whose category is Supermarket.

I want to get the category of business listings without scraping the site.
Is there an API provided by Google which outputs category based on id or something. I've tried using Google Maps and Places API but it didn't work. I'll be using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business listing is quite a broad type to be looked in the list of the [categories supported by the Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). Please be more specific while selecting the business type in the list, you would find a lot of options there.

The API request should look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=establishment&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

For a tutorial of Places APIon Python specifically, Please click the following [Link](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/using-the-google-places-api-in-python/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) for this. All you need to do is specify [business type.](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

For your case, you will need to add `type=grocery_or_supermarket` in your request URL